# Server doesn't receive message

Tags: java, netty

im currently trying to learn netty and just nothing works... ) :
Somehow, the server doesnt receives any messages from the client and i don't know why. Please keep in mind that i have never build a working application in netty so i have absolutly no experience. I'd be happy if someone could help me.
Im posting a LOT of code and im sorry about that, but i have no idea how to make this question smaller.

So, this is my code:

```
    new Server().run();
    Client client = new Client();
    client.run();

    while(true){
        System.out.println("sending message to server...");
        client.sendMessage(new PacketPing(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

This is my client:

```
private Channel channel;
@Override public void run() {
    ChannelFuture future = new Bootstrap().
            group(new NioEventLoopGroup()).
            channel(NioSocketChannel.class).
            handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(
                            new ObjectEncoder(),
                            new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                            new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("client received message!");
                                }
                            });
                }
            }).connect("localhost", 40401);
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.channel = future.channel();
}
public void sendMessage(Object msg) {
    channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
}
```

And this is my server:

```
@Override public void run() {
    new ServerBootstrap().
            group(new NioEventLoopGroup(1), new NioEventLoopGroup()).
            channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).
            handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).
            childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(
                            new ObjectEncoder(),
                            new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                            new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("server received a message!");
                                }
                            });
                }
            }).bind(40401);
}
```

I think im missing some fundamental understanding and i have no idea where to start debugging. The code is pretty simple so it should be easy for everybody familiar with netty to answer this ( :
Thanks @everybody!

Console:

```
Nov 18, 2016 7:47:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRegistered
INFORMATION: [id: 0x52b5b879] REGISTERED
Nov 18, 2016 7:47:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler bind
INFORMATION: [id: 0x52b5b879] BIND: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:40401
Nov 18, 2016 7:47:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelActive
INFORMATION: [id: 0x52b5b879, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:40401] ACTIVE
Nov 18, 2016 7:47:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
INFORMATION: [id: 0x52b5b879, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:40401] RECEIVED: [id: 0xdda43b4c, L:/127.0.0.1:40401 - R:/127.0.0.1:56421]
sending message to server...
sending message to server...
sending message to server...
sending message to server...
sending message to server...
sending message to server...
```

Comment: Does the channel future you get from `writeAndFlush` indicate success?

Comment: No, it returns false... but why?

Comment: Check the cause, call `.cause().printStackTrace()` (on the channel future) on it to print it to the console

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: PacketPing (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion).
I dont understand this...

Comment: My ObjectDecoder doesnt seem to work, right?

Comment: Does your `PingPacket` object implements `Serializable` , according to the documentation of [`ObjectEncoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoder.html) it requires that

Comment: wow, thats it. i cant believe i didnt noticed that. Thanks for your help <3!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netty doesn't write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862160/netty-doesnt-write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the bug, thanks to Ferrybig. My packet was just not serializable.