# Netty doesn't write

Tags: java, netty

When trying to write with netty, the written data never ends up at the remote side, confirmed with Wireshark.

I have tried:

```
//Directly using writeAndFlush
channel.writeAndFlush(new Packet());

//Manually flushing
channel.write(new Packet());
channel.flush();

// Even sending bytes won't work:
channel.writeAndFlush(new byte[]{1,2,3});
```

No exception is caught when I wrap it in `try{...}catch(Throwable e){e.printStackTrace();}`

What can I do to debug this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Netty is asynchronous, meaning that it won't throw exceptions when a write failed. Instead of throwing exceptions, it returns a `Future<?>` that will be updated when the request is done. Make sure to log any exceptions coming from this as your first debugging steps:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(...).addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(Future<Object> future) {
        // TODO: Use proper logger in production here
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("Data written succesfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data failed to write:");
            future.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Or more simply:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(...).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE);
```

After you get the root cause of the exception, there could be multiple problems:

## `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:`
`unsupported message type: <type> (expected: ...)`

*Notice:* This also throws when using an [`ObjectEncoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoder.html), but your object does not implements [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html?is-external=true)

A default Netty channel can only send `ByteBuf`s and `FileRegion`s. You need to convert your objects to these types either by adding more handlers to the pipeline, or converting them manually to `ByteBuf`s.

A `ByteBuf` is the Netty variant of a byte array, but has the potential for performance because it can be stored in the direct memory space.

The following handlers are commonly used:

> To convert a `String` use a `StringEncoder`
>   To convert a `Serializable` use a `ObjectEncoder` (warning, not compatible with normal Java object streams)
>   To convert a `byte[]` use a `ByteArrayEncoder`

*Notice:* Since TCP is a stream based protocol, you usually want some form of packet sizes attached, since you may not receive exact packets that you write. See [Dealing with a Stream-based Transport](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-11) in the Netty wiki for more information.