# netty client can't receive the response from server when using DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder and decode

Tags: netty

client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup workgroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workgroup)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class) 
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("$_".getBytes());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024,buf));
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler());
                    }
                });

        ChannelFuture cf = b.connect("127.0.0.1",8765); 

//        cf.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("aa$_".getBytes()));
//        cf.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("bbbb$_".getBytes()));

        cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        workgroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

}

clientHandler:

```
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("aa$_".getBytes()));
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("bbbb$_".getBytes()));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            String response = (String)msg;
            System.out.println("Server feedback: "+ response);
        }finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        final ServerBootstrap  b = new ServerBootstrap();

        b.group(bossGroup,workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("$_".getBytes());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024,buf));
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
                    }
                });

        ChannelFuture future = b.bind(8765).sync();

        future.channel().closeFuture().sync();

        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();

    }
}
```

Serverhandler：

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        String str = (String)msg;
        System.out.println("Client: "+str);
//        String response = "Server";
//        response = response+"$_";
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Server!!!!$_".getBytes()));
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

If i send messages directly through the client use `cf.channel()` like this：

```
cf.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("aa$_".getBytes()));
cf.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("bbbb$_".getBytes()));
```

Both the client and the server receive no data.

but if i comment out the code of decode and DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder in client(the clientHandler need use Bytebuf) ,both the client and the server can receive the message,although the message which the server received were unpacked (only client has the problem)

```
Server feedback: Server!!!!$_Server!!!!$_
```

If i send the message in clientHandler throuth channelActive :

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Start");
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("aa$_".getBytes()));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("bbbb$_".getBytes()));
}
```

it works fine.

```
Server feedback: Server!!!!
Server feedback: Server!!!!
```

What is the difference between sending the message with `cf.channel()` and `ctx` in clientHandler?

Netty 4.1.15

Comment: Try printing out the exception that writeAndFlush returns inside its future, see [Netty doesn't write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862161/1542723) how to quickly print this. You are probably sending data before the connection is established , try adding a `.sync()` after the connect method

Comment: thanks，I did forget to add `.syn ()` after the connect method.