# How to fix incomplete download from netty server

Tags: java, netty

I'm implementing some simple netty server and client to send and revieve files. Something which is similar to cloud storage.

I have a server which handles incoming requests and sends the files back to the client. I also want my apps to be able to handle with big files, that's why I divide such files into chunks and send them chunk by chunk. But there's an issue I can't resolve.

Let's say:

- We have a `4 gb` file on a server.
- It is divided into 40 000 chunks.
- Then they are sent to a client application, and I can see that all the chunks at the server are written into socket, as I use int field as a message number (chunk number) and put into log a message number which is being written.

But then when a client receives messages (chunks), in the case of large files the process doesn't finish successfully and only some (it depends on the size of a file) of the chunks are received by a client.

A client starts receiving consecutive messages - `1, 2, 3, 4 ... 27878, 27879` and then **stops with no exception**, although the last message from server was, for example 40000.

Almost forgot to say that I use JavaFX for the client app.

So, I tried to play with xms xmx java vm options but it didn't help.

Server

```
public class Server {
    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup mainGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(mainGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
                                    new ObjectDecoder(Constants.FRAME_SIZE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                                    new MainHandler()
                            );
                        }
                    })
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture future = b.bind(8189).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            mainGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Server().run();

    }
}
```

Server handler

```
@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (msg == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (msg instanceof FileRequest) {
                FileRequest fr = (FileRequest) msg;
                switch (fr.getFileCommand()) {
                    case DOWNLOAD:
                        sendFileToClient(ctx, fr.getFilename());
                        break;
                    case LIST_FILES:
                        listFiles(ctx);
                        break;
                    case DELETE:
                        deleteFileOnServer(fr);
                        listFiles(ctx);
                        break;
                    case SEND:
                        saveFileOnServer(fr);
                        listFiles(ctx);
                        break;
                    case SEND_PARTIAL_DATA:
                        savePartialDataOnServer(fr);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
```

Methods for sending files in chunks

```
private void sendFileToClient(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String fileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("server_storage/" + fileName);
        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            if (Files.size(path) > Constants.FRAME_SIZE) {
                sendServerDataFrames(ctx, path);
                ctx.writeAndFlush(new FileRequest(FileCommand.LIST_FILES));
            } else {
                FileMessage fm = new FileMessage(path);
                ctx.writeAndFlush(fm);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendServerDataFrames(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Path path) throws IOException {
        byte[] byteBuf = new byte[Constants.FRAME_CHUNK_SIZE];

        FileMessage fileMessage = new FileMessage(path, byteBuf, 1);
        FileRequest fileRequest = new FileRequest(FileCommand.SEND_PARTIAL_DATA, fileMessage);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path.toFile());
        int read;
        while ((read = fis.read(byteBuf)) > 0) {
            if (read < Constants.FRAME_CHUNK_SIZE) {
                byteBuf = Arrays.copyOf(byteBuf, read);
                fileMessage.setData(byteBuf);
            }
            ctx.writeAndFlush(fileRequest);
            fileMessage.setMessageNumber(fileMessage.getMessageNumber() + 1);
        }

        System.out.println("server_storage/" + path.getFileName() +  ", server last frame number: " + fileMessage.getMessageNumber());
        System.out.println("server_storage/" + path.getFileName() +  ": closing file stream.");

        fis.close();
    }
```

client handlers

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Network.start();
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    AbstractMessage am = Network.readObject();
                    if (am instanceof FileMessage) {
                        FileMessage fm = (FileMessage) am;
                        Files.write(Paths.get("client_storage/" + fm.getFilename()), fm.getData(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                        refreshLocalFilesList();
                    }
                    if (am instanceof FilesListMessage) {
                        FilesListMessage flm = (FilesListMessage) am;
                        refreshServerFilesList(flm.getFilesList());
                    }
                    if (am instanceof FileRequest) {
                        FileRequest fr = (FileRequest) am;
                        switch (fr.getFileCommand()) {
                            case DELETE:
                                deleteFile(fr.getFilename());
                                break;
                            case SEND_PARTIAL_DATA:
                                receiveFrames(fr);
                                break;
                            case LIST_FILES:
                                refreshLocalFilesList();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Network.stop();
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        refreshLocalFilesList();
        Network.sendMsg(new FileRequest(FileCommand.LIST_FILES));
    }

 private void receiveFrames(FileRequest fm) throws IOException {
        Utils.processBytes(fm.getFileMessage(), "client_storage/");
    }


public final class Utils {

    public static void processBytes(FileMessage fm, String pathPart) {
        Path path = Paths.get(pathPart + fm.getFilename());
        byte[] data = fm.getData();

        System.out.println(pathPart + path.getFileName() + ": " + fm.getMessageNumber());

        try {
            if (fm.getMessageNumber() == 1) {
                Files.write(path, data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
            } else {
                Files.write(path, data, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

That what I see on server.

```
server_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: 42151
server_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: 42152
server_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso, server last frame number: 42153
server_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: closing file stream.
```

And this one is on a client.

```
client_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: 29055
client_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: 29056
client_storage/DVD5_OFFICE_2010_SE_SP2_VOLUME_X86_RU-KROKOZ.iso: 29057
```

And there is no issue when sending files from the client to the the server. I can see in debugger and in the windows task manager that both processes are working simultaniously but it's not like this when a file is sent from the server to the client. First all the chunks are read and then they are sent to a client and it starts to receive them but failed to get all of them.
Please help. I have no idea what it could be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure to catch exception by the future of `writeAndFlush`, they might contain the clue to your problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862161/1542723 for an example how to read those exceptions

Comment: Thank you. It really helped to find out the reason. It was obvious - netty couldn't release the memory taken by messge from server as the message class doesn't implement ReferenceCounted interface.

Comment: Another way to solve it, would be using a [`ChunkedInput`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedInput.html) in combination with a [`ChunkedWriteHandler`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.html) so the next part of the file is only send when the network layer has processed the first part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netty doesn't write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862160/netty-doesnt-write)

Comment: Yes, it's better to use already implemented functionality than to invent a bycicle again.